# How can I make a table_query.sql?

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, ubuntu

https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan

I am going to the street on the above site. Now I am making databases and users.

Come out of psql by pressing `ctrl + D` and also come out of postgres user by pressing `ctrl + D` again. From there,

```
$ psql - d simplech_db - U simplech_role
```

After entering, I tried to make tables and functions.

```
\ i create_table_query.sql

\ i functions.sql

\ i functions_moderator.sql
```

Even if you enter, nothing will react. There is no error.

I am doing it on Linux, but where was the problem?

Comment: See if this helps https://superuser.com/questions/701415/how-do-i-execute-run-a-sql-file-in-postgresql-9-2-6-centos?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I'm sorry. I am using ubuntu instead of CentOS.

Comment: Have you tried the command by chance?
OS shouldn't make a different as PostgreSQL is a third party software and all the commands are pretty much same, no matter what OS you're using.

Comment: can not. When I enter, "There is no such file" will be displayed.

Comment: Well, this is a different problem now. Have you tried giving the full file path instead of the file name only?

Comment: Yes. I could not do it. Perhaps, is this to import a SQL file downloaded from the above site and create a table? If so, please tell me how to do it. By the way, the downloaded place is "E: / simplechan - master / sql / three SQL files".